# Running git bisect while using libraries that are under active development

Tags: git, git-bisect

I have two projects, LogViewer, and LogAnalyzer that are both under development in separate git repositories, and LogViewer depends on LogAnalyzer. I'm trying to do a git bisect on LogViewer, but every time I try to test a new commit, I have to find and checkout a commit in LogAnalyser that has the right API, which is annoying and time consuming. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why aren't you using git submodules? I think that would solve your problem (if you used them from the beginning, not sure what to do now).

Comment: Yeah, the LogAnalyzer began development long before the LogViewer, and is used in too many places now to make it a submodule. Our shop also hasn't even fully converted to Git yet so I don't that is going to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

LogViewer might know what version/tag of LogAnalyzer it depends on. It should be easy to create a script that checks out the corresponding version of LogAnalyzer.

As LogAnalyzer has an API it should also change version whenever that API changes.

Comment: Yea, the release version changes whenever the API changes, but the development version doesn't have a new version for every API change.